# Why is java returning encoded values different

Tags: java

I am not quite sure why does java return %27+ for special characters in the name.

For example, the value I am trying to encode was "Mc' Donald". Its encoding to "Mc%27+Donald" when it should be "Mc%27%20Donald". reason why I replaced in the first place is db has ' instead of ' so replacing and encoding again.

```
lastName = URLEncoder.encode(lastName.replace("&apos;", "'"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML encoding, `+` is a valid replacement for SPACE (`%20`) as well.

Comment: Pablo - quick question.. restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString()) is converting already encoded %27 to %2527 because I think its encoding % again.. How can I make sure it doesnt encode again?

When I dont UrlEncode beforehand, apostrophe is not getting encoded at .toUriString()..

Comment: I see what your problem is. I don't see an easy solution other than make sure you don't double encode your values when passing them around. And you're probably right. `%27` is being encoded to `%2527` because `%` is being encoded again. Maybe you could try decoding before encoding?